# Bash recursively execute a command on each directory

Tags: linux, bash, console

I have a directory with many subdirectories inside, i want to execute a command on each of those subdirectories.

What i want to do is run 'svn up'

this is what i have tried so far

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec svn "up '{}'" \;
```

and

```
for dir in * do cd $dir; svn up; cd ..;
```

None of them works so far (I have tried many things without luck)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need a trailing slash on the glob:

```
for d in */; do # only match directories
  ( cd "$d" && svn up ) # Use a subshell to avoid having to cd back to the root each time.
done
```

Comment: @ArnoldRoa heh, but the trailing slash is the real *answer* here. :P

Answer (score 3):

This works for me - the `-d` checks for a directory:

```
for f in *; do if [ -d "$f" ]; then cd "$f"; echo "$f"; cd ..; fi; done
```

`echo "$f"` can be substituted for whatever command you wish to run from inside each directory.

Note that this, and the [trailing `/` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22635481/2088135), both match symbolic links, as well as files. If you want to avoid this behaviour (only enter real directories), you can do this:

```
for f in *; do if [ -d "$f" -a ! -L "$f" ]; then cd "$f"; echo "$f"; cd ..; fi done
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec svn up "{}" \;
```

But it tried to update the current directory, which should be ommited. (althought it works for me because current dir is not a svn directory)